# create batch file to copy folder contents with dynamic name

Tags: batch-file, copy, command, directory, dos

I am absolutely brand new to any kind of development but need a batch job to copy a file from one folder to another.
The problem is that the source folder is dynamically named. The folder name will contain the current date and a suffix number  (eg. "TestRun_20141106_13") - so I will never be able to determine the 'latest' version of the folder before running the batch / copy job.

Can anyone help please? I know this will be easy for someone but as I said, I am a complete noob!!

Thanks in advance.
Jamie

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I havent been doing .bat for that long either, but i think i can help!

Here is a code for the movement of the file!

Dealing wiwth dynamically named folder...

```
@echo off 
set /p txtfile=Filename without Path assumes c:\: 
echo.%txtfile% 
copy %txtfile% z:\testing\dealer.txt 
echo Come back to this window when Agent is done with process. The copy file will be deleted. 
@pause 
copy %txtfile% c:\somefolder\namedsuccess\%txtfile% 
del z:\testing\dealer.txt 
exit
```

You will have to place your own variables in there my friend!

For moving of the files!
Easy part!

```
move /-y "Folder Path that files are in*(Any specific keyword?)*" "(Dest. folder)"
```

Comment: Select your code area, then press `{}` (on top of edit window) to auto-indent by 4 spaces which formats & highlights your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR "C:\Example" /s /b /a:d') DO SET CurrentDir=%%A
@ECHO.%CurrentDir%
```

Replace "C:\Example" with the Path your Folders are in, 
save it to a File (*.bat/*.cmd) and execute.

The last step - Echo will return the most bottom foldername.