# Batch-File to copy code to a file in a folder with dynamic name

Tags: batch-file

We have customized an application (Polarion ALM) by adding some CSS-code to stylesheets from the application. However, those stylesheets are located in a server-path, which is affected from updates. For this issue we have started creating a very simple Batch-file to copy lines of code to the stylesheets.

Here an example:

```
echo .anyclass {color:red;} >> \\serveradress\folder_3.18.0\Chrome.css
```

The script itself works fine - however the problem is that with every update of the application the foldername "folder_3.18.0" changes, in which the stylesheet is located, for example to "folder_3.18.1" or "folder_3.19.0" (At least only the number changes).

Is there any trick to handle in the script this dynamic number behind the "folder_"? Or any workaround? Unfortunately I have to stick to the "not-update-safe" path to locate the stylesheet.

There is a similar question in this forum, but I don't understand how to transfer it to my Use-Case - as I am totally new to Batch-Files:
[create batch file to copy folder contents with dynamic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785140/create-batch-file-to-copy-folder-contents-with-dynamic-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /D %%A IN ("\\servername\plugins\com.softwarename.alm.ui_") DO SET "folder=%%A"
echo %folder%
```

will return you the last matching folder. So the your example changes to:

```
echo .anyclass {color:red;} >> "%folder%\Chrome.css"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan. One little issue left: Now my "folder" has a name format like: "\\servername\plugins\com.softwarename.alm.ui_*". Does powershell recognize that "."? Do I have to change all "folder" in the code with "com.softwarename.alm.ui"? 

Excuse please my rookie questions :)

Comment: This is batch, not powershell. A dot (`.`)  is a valid character for a folder- or file-name. The `for /D` looks for matching folders, so if you look for `\\servername\plugins\com.softwarename.alm.ui_something`, yes, you have to use `\\servername\plugins\com.softwarename.alm.ui_*` (the known part plus a wildcard for the unknown part)